# Ruby date conversion from 10-Aug-14 to dd/mm/yy

Tags: ruby, date

I'm reading from xls & csv files with the dates that have the following formatting;

```
10-Aug-14
```

And I need them to be: dd/mm/yyyy (11/08/2014)

Have tried the date_format gem the standard Ruby Date & Time classes with no luck.

Inspection shows it's an array consisting of a Date object & a String;

```
p date_start  #=> #<Date: -4712-01-01 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> "11-Aug-14"

puts date_start            #=> -4712-01-01
                           #=> 11-Aug-14

puts date_start.class      #=> Array

puts date_start[0].class   #=> Date

puts date_start[1].class   #=> String
```

Any idea how I can parse this into a date that Ruby understands. 
Also I need to get the weekdays in numbers between two dates so getting this right is key.

Comment: Could you add the code you are using to read the CSV and Excel files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For parse date:

```
my_date = Date.strptime("10-Aug-14 ", "%d-%b-%y")
```

To the other format(dd/mm/yy):

```
puts my_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

For weekdays count you can use 'weekdays gem' --> https://github.com/mdarby/weekdays